# Request.IsAjaxRequest() is false

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In the view:

```
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")" data-atpl-ajax="true" data-atpl-target="#results">

    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">IP:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ClientIP" name="ClientIP">
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name">
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Show Results</button>
</form>
```

The JavaScript file:

```
$(function () {
    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
        var $form = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: $form.serialize()
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($form.attr("data-atpl-target"));
            $target.replaceWith(data);
        });

        return false;
    };

    $("form[data-atpl-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);

});
```

I have also ensured the proper order of js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

But, in controller action,

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

returns false. What's the issue here?

Comment: Is something removing the X-Requested-With header?

Comment: Make sure that you have "<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> " in your web.config

Comment: @ShaiAharoni It is already enabled.

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni It's MVC 5 on VS 2015

Comment: In the controller check you request headers for "X-Requested-With", see if the key exists and check for its value

Comment: @ShaiAharoni X-Requested-With is not set.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, in order for `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` to work, the `X-Requested-With` header must be present in the AJAX request. jQuery should be adding this automatically. Looking around, I've only found exceptions to that with very old versions of jQuery. If you're not using the latest 1.* or 2.* (depending on your need for past IE version support), you should upgrade.

Short of that, you can manually add the header. It's not ideal, as you're pretty much just glossing over the issue, but worse come to worse, just add the following:

```
var options = {
    url: $form.attr("action"),
    type: $form.attr("method"),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you open your browser network tab and inspect the request to see what header value it is sending. I think one of your script is scrapping this header value. By default it sends this header value.

Comment: Interestingly, I see the deprecated `live()` method calls in `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` script. :)

Comment: @Shyju Pasting the request headers:

GET /Logs?Category=All&ClientIP=&URI=&StartDate=2015-12-01+11%3A47%3A05+PM&EndDate=2015-12-28+11%3A47%3A07+PM&Message= HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:28676
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:28676/Logs?Category=All&ClientIP=&URI=&StartDate=2015-12-01+11%3A35%3A35+PM&EndDate=2015-12-28+11%3A35%3A38+PM&Message=

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but using Ajax.BeginForm() worked for me. I have got rid of the form element and implemented this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "GET",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "results"
                }))
                {
                     //input fields go here
                }
```

Interested to know what caused this behaviour.